# Does the CMD command shutdown -i work on any and every PC connected to a network?

Tags: remote-shutdown

I'm aware that the CMD command `shutdown -i` can be used to open a GUI interface to configure a remote shutdown of a computer on my LAN.

So, can I shut down any and every computer on a LAN using this command? Or rather, my question is, is there any way to prevent a person connected to my LAN from executing such a remote shutdown on my PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Access to the Remote Registry or membership in the Administrators group on the remote computer is the minimum required to complete this procedure.

So it's only possible if you give users permission to do it by granting them one of the above permissions.